# What simulator is used for the nokia 7230 phone?

Tags: java-me, mobile, mobile-phones, nokia, simulator

What simulator is used for the nokia 7230 phone for testing MIDP applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically nokia 7230 is S40 series mobile. For more info see this link,

[Nokia 7230](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/7230/)

Comment: Hi bhakki,  Thanks for your kind information.But I will download the S40 series sdk from nokia site.After installing it cannot run it have some problem.

Comment: Hi bhakki, if i click the "emulator.exe" of the nokia s40 series sdk.Then the message box is appeared & diplaying the message as "The application as failed to start because MSVCR71.dll was not found".Help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

[Download MSVCR71.dll](http://www.driverskit.com/dll/msvcr71.dll/2373.html) and copy paste into C:\WINDOWS\system32 this folder. Now check your emulator.